# Failure/Error: get("/instructions/new").should route_to("instructions#new")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

**instructions_routing_spec.rb**

```
require "spec_helper"

describe InstructionsController do

  before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

  describe "routing" do
    it "routes to #new" do
      get("/instructions/new").should route_to("instructions#new")
    end
  end
end
```

**instructions_controller.rb**

```
class InstructionsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml, :json

  layout :single_column_layout

  before_filter :admin_only, :except => [:show]

  def new
    @instruction = Instruction.new    
    respond_with(@instruction)
  end    
end
```

**spec_helper.rb**

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'forgery'
require 'populators'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :view
  config.mock_with :rspec

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/test/fixtures"

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.after(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
  resources :instructions, :path => "help", :as => "help"
  resources :instructions, :only => [:index,:show]
```

**rake routes output**

```
instructions#destroy
                      instructions GET        /instructions(.:format)
instructions#index
                      instruction GET      /instructions/:id(.:format)
```

Having Following Error;

> Failure/Error: get("/instructions/new").should
>   route_to("instructions#new")
>          The recognized options <{"id"=>"new", "action"=>"show", "controller"=>"instructions"}> did not match <{"action"=>"new",
>   "controller"=>"instructions"}>, difference: <{"id"=>"new",
>   "action"=>"new"}>.
>          <{"action"=>"new", "controller"=>"instructions"}> expected but was
>          <{"id"=>"new", "action"=>"show", "controller"=>"instructions"}>.
>
> **Note:** rpsec 2.11.0, rails 3.2.19, ruby 1.8.7

It should work like */:controller/:action/:id* but I dont know what am doing wrong please help .... !

Comment: Give your routes file content, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there may be a couple of issues here. Firstly to use parameters in the matcher you would need to do something like the following:

```
  get("/instructions/new/1").should route_to("instructions#new", id: 1)
```

This assumes you have specified your route as `/:instructions/:new/:id`

If your route is of the form `/:instructions/:id/:new` then naturally you would need to modify the matcher accordingly:

```
  get("/instructions/1/new").should route_to("instructions#new", id: 1)
```

However, I feel you have set up your route wrong in the first place - normally when you call the `new` action, on a controller, you wouldn't be providing an `id` for the resource (after all it hasn't yet been created). So you might want to consider changing the route and leaving your matcher as is.

The output you have supplied for rake routes doesn't look right, seems some of it is missing, however you should probably change your routing to the following:

```
resources :instructions, :only => [:new, :index, :show]
```

Comment: I know it will pass my test but it is not a good way :( .... may b i need to do something with my routing

Comment: yes hence the last paragraph in my solution. You need to provide your `routes.rb` and the output from `rake routes` in your question for further insight.

Comment: `resources :instructions, :path => "help", :as => "help"
  resources :instructions, :only => [:index,:show]` this is what i have in my routes.rb and `instructions#destroy
                      instructions GET        /instructions(.:format)                                                                  instructions#index
                       instruction GET        /instructions/:id(.:format)` in rake routes output

Comment: can you edit your question and add `routes.rb` to that and the result of `rake routes` please.

Comment: Yeah it will work thanx :) I have alot of confusion in rspec need many things to sort out let see :)

Comment: it's a steep learning curve but you'll get there .... writing specs is a great way to learn about Rails and not just rspec.